# Location of equation in LyX

Tags: align

Usually, an equation of the type `ctrl`+`shift`+`m` is centered.

I found in one of the questions here that adding the custom `fleqn` will left align those equations.

How can I make them left aligned, but slightly right?

(They are already a bit right, but I want them to be more to the right)

I use LyX and not LaTeX.

Comment: the key strokes you mention are for some editor that you have not mentioned.  `fleqn` is not for left aligning equations, use the `fleqn` option to `amsmath`  to left align, then set `\mathindent` to move them a fixed amount to the right

Comment: I forgot to write that I use LyX and not LaTeX. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean by "*They are already a bit right*". Post a screenshot of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Possibly `\setlength{\mathindent}{50pt}` added to Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble. Edit: this is what David was referring to. Adjust the length to whatever you prefer.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just had the opposite problem, where I could not figure out why LyX was left aligning my equations instead of centering them.

So here is the solution for both LyX and LaTeX, as well as centered and custom left-aligned:

## LaTeX

### Centered equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    a=b
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Left-aligned equation:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    a=b
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Left aligned equation with custom indent:

(as already pointed out in the comments by  Torbjørn T.)

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\mathindent}{50pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    a=b
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

## LyX

For LyX, you just need to go to **Document settings -> Math options**. Then depending on what you want, do one of the following:

- Centered equation: Uncheck *Indent formulas*
- Left-aligned equation: Check *Indent formulas* and select *Default*
- Left aligned equation with custom indent: Check *Indent formulas* and select *Custom*, then enter a custom value and unit as in the image below:

[image: LyX, Document Settings, Math Options]